# Using Affine Transform to rotate polygon

Tags: java, polygon

I'm currently trying to rotate a polygon using the Affine Transform class. Using the rotate method, the polygon's graphical representation updates, but the bounding box of the polygon doesn't update. How can I rotate the polygon in addition to updating it's coordinates?

Comment: What do you mean by the polygon's "bounding box"? Are you storing this as part of the polygon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new Shape instead of just rotating the polygon as your paint it. For example:

```
Polygon shape = new Polygon();
shape.addPoint(...);
....
Rectangle bounds = shape.getBounds();
AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), bounds.width / 2, bounds.height / 2);

Path2D path = (shape instanceof Path2D) ? (Path2D)shape : new GeneralPath(shape);
Shape rotated = path.createTransformedShape( transform );
System.out.println(rotated.getBounds());
```

Comment: Creating the new shape seemed to work, giving me updated coordinates. I don't quite get the path part however... How could the polygon be an instance of Path2d?

Comment: It isn't, thats why the code does a check. In this case the Polygon is first convert to a GeneralPath, so it can be rotated. (I just updated the code so that the "shape" variable is used instead of the "polygon" variable I originally had. Hope this makes more sense)